# Integral equation with a cosine-like transform

Tags: integration, analysis, fourier-analysis, transformation, fourier-transform

Suppose that we have the following integral equation
$$
\int_0^\infty F(q) \cos q z \, \mathrm{d} q = \int_0^\infty G(q) \cos q z \, \mathrm{d} q \, , 
$$
wherein $F(q)$ and $G(q)$ are arbitrary functions of the wavenumber $q$ which they are not necessary even functions. I was wondering whether $F(q) = G(q)$ holds in this case.
I think that such equality would be guaranteed if $F$ and $G$ are even functions in virtue of Fourier transforms. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

a

Comment: Evenness of $F$ and $G$ is irrelevant because they are only evaluated for positive $q$, isn't it?

Comment: @Rahul Yes they are both evaluated for positive $q$. However, the integral equation cannot in principle be rewritten as a Fourier integral in a common way if they are not even functions. Therefore, writing $F=G$ may not hold always. I don't know.

Comment: Well you can always replace $F$ with an even function $F_e(x) = \begin{cases}F(x) & \text{if $x\ge 0$} \\ F(-x) & \text{otherwise,}\end{cases}$ and similarly for $G$. Then your equation can be written as $\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty F_e(q)\cos qz\,\mathrm dq = \frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty G_e(q)\cos qz\,\mathrm dq$.

Comment: @Rahul thanks for your answer. Then the identity holds as well. Is this the case even if $F(-x)$ is not really valued take for example $F(x) = K_0(x)$ where $K_0$ being the zeroth order modified Bessel function of the second kind.